# Elementor: Ability to show the same page with 2 different templates

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to show the same CPT with 2 different templates.
The use case is to have a "print" layout for the same page. In this case CSS media queries are not optimal as my print layout is quite different.

I have a feeling that it should be possible to achieve by giving the template via GET parameter. For example when using the preview button on my template the template slug is here, but I can't get it to work outside of the preview mode.

```
my_site.com/?elementor_library=profile-pdf&preview_id=25821&preview_nonce=89f2d8e6d4&preview=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template_include Hook to change the core functionality and choose the template by yourself.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/